# Position tooltip jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my tooltip, but i have problem in ie5: http://jsfiddle.net/pnv4xus4/

In mozilla and chrome appears correctly, the tooltip beneath the text box:

[image]

In my ie5 the tooltip appears on the left side of the page, completely out of place. To solve this changed my js for the following:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input.age').tooltip({
            position:'bottom bottom',
            relative:true,
            content: function () {
                return $(this).attr('title');
            }
        });
        $('input.age').tooltip('open')
    });
</script>
```

That is, here I added the position, but it asks me as follows (the tooltip is above the input, and I want to get underneath):

[image]

for finding hard to be the ie5 version, is there any way to get the tooltip fixed regardless of the version and the browser?

Comment: ***IE5***...? I hope that's a typo.

Comment: ie5?? You should focus on making the code work on IE9+ - Even Microsoft doesn't support IE8 and below.

Comment: Even on [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/de-de/virtualization-tools) you can't get the ie5 vm anymore

Comment: Yes, on my pc it appears well, but on the client does not. I went to the ie and methyl programmer in order to see which was the version that it happened and gave in version 5 ...

Comment: I wouldn't even worry about IE5, like they said above. It's completely irrelevant.